# Facebook Admin access granted

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My employer granted me admin access to his page so I can do some work
on it, but how do I find where to access the page?

Answer (score 2):

If you have admin access, simply login to facebook and click on the page on the left hand side. Your view of the page will automatically have changed.

Comment: If it is not in the sidebar, you can enter the name of the page in the search field within the blue bar at the top.  Also there should be an option to use Facebook as the page in the ▾ menu in the upper right corner within the blue bar.

Comment: It would also send you a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Basically

1) you will receive a `notification to confirm` the invitation of admin access of a certain Page

2) If you already accept the invitation, you can easily `switch between your private account and page` to use as either. Ref: pls see the image.

[image]

3) Just `click on the page` that you want to use, then the Interface will be changed to use as a selected Page.

Hope this helps.